# Best structure for accessing an object knowing a unique property

Tags: c#, performance, dictionary, optimization, collections

I have an array of elements that I need to access quite often, and quite fast. I know that a property from those elements is unique and I inject the array into a wrapper class, which builds a dictionary from this property. Since a dictionary access is way faster than a LINQ query on the array, I thought that'd be efficient.

But, despite it is working well, the solution looks a bit weird : I am storing the object as a value into the dictionary, and part of it as a key.

Is there any better suited structure/way of doing it?

```
 public class FooItem
{

    public string Id { get; set; } //UNIQUE

    public double Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }

}

public class FoosManager
{
    private Dictionary<string, FooItem> _dic;

    public FooManager(IEnumerable<FooItem> items) {
        _dic = new Dictionary<string, FooItem>(
            items.ToDictionary(x => x.Id, x => x),
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }

    public FooItem this[string id] => GetItem(id); //Indexer

    private FooItem GetItem(string id) {
        if (_dic.ContainsKey(id)) 
            return null;

        return _dic[id];
    }

}
```

Comment: It's perfectly normal to have a dictionary where the values are objects, and the keys are the IDs of those objects.

Comment: @JonasHøgh ok, good to know. So this is the most efficient way of doing it in terms of lookup speed?

Comment: `private FooItem GetItem(string id) => _dic.TryGetValue(id, out var item) ? item : null;`

Comment: I think your FoosManager class is largely redundant. It doesn't really add anything that storing the dictionary as an IReadonlyDictionary<string, FooItem> wouldn't give you

Comment: @JonasHøgh point taken, I use it mostly for securing serialization/deserialization from JSON (especially the dictionary serialization) through methods not represented here. Does it induce a performance issue since 1- it is instantiated once for all 2- it is mostly transparent , forwarding the call to the dictionary

Comment: If you used to live with a linear array search on every lookup, you can most likely live with an extra method call, assuming the JIT cannot inline it.

Comment: @JonasHøgh I never lived with a linear array search on every lookup, what do you mean?

Comment: @XavierAM you implied that you were using Linq to search for the FooItems previously, that would probably have linear running time. Anyway, I wouldn't worry about the number of calls unless you're on an extremely hot code path.

Comment: @JonasHøgh ok my bad, this was an english mistake then. I actually never used LINQ to search for items, I was just explaining my thinking. Anyway, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your code into

```
public class FoosManager {
  private Dictionary<string, FooItem> _dic;

  public FooManager(IEnumerable<FooItem> items) {
    if (null == items)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(items));

    // Let's do it in one go:
    _dic = items.ToDictionary(
       item => item.Id, 
       item => item, 
       StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
  }

  // No need in GetItem, ContainsKey etc.
  public FooItem this[string id] => 
    _dic.TryGetValue(id, out var value) ? value : null;
}
```

As for `FooItem` I'd make it *immutable* (at least, `Id`; otherwise one can put `FooItem` into `FoosManager` and then *change* the `Id`)

```
  public class FooItem {
    public FooItem(string id, double value1, string value2) {
      if (null == id)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(id)); 

      Id = id;
      Value1 = value1;
      Value2 = value2;
    } 

    public string Id { get; } 

    public double Value1 { get; }
    public string Value2 { get; }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Using strings as keys of the `Dictionary`, the same strings that are stored in the `Id` property, is OK because the strings are not copied. Only references to the string are copied (8 bytes per reference according to my tests). Unless of course you create explicitly copies like this:

```
var dictionary = items.ToDictionary(x => new String(x.Id.ToCharArray()));
```

In this case the memory allocated for the strings will be doubled, although the functionality of the `Dictionary` will remain unaffected.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this detailed answered.